# Subir archivo a directorio y a base de datos mysql

Tags: php, fileupload

tengo el error siguiente error al mover el archivo seguido de  SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data, al parecer por que intento subir el archivo mediante http, ya le di permisos a mi directorio en el servidor que se llama fotos pero no logro subirlo e insertar la ruta en la base de datos en entorno local si me funciona pero al hacerlo en el hosting me marca ese error que me esta faltando para poder subirlo adjunto mi codigo:

```
if ($_FILES['archivo']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    
     
    $nombreArchivo = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
    $rutaDestino =  'C:/xampp1/htdocs/db_server/fotos/'.$nombreArchivo;
    
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'],$rutaDestino)) {

        $idempleado = $_POST['idempleado'];
        
        $conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "db");
       

        $sql = "UPDATE usuarios SET userfoto='$nombreArchivo',rutafoto='$rutaDestino' WHERE id_usuarios = '$idusuario'";
        if ($conexion->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo json_encode(['code' => '1']);
        } else {
            echo json_encode(['code' => '0' . $conn->error]);
        }

        $conexion->close();
    } else {
        echo "Error al mover el archivo a la ruta de destino.";
    }
    echo "Error al subir el archivo.";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

En el hosting no existe la ruta:

```
'C:/xampp1/htdocs/db_server/fotos/
```

Por lo general los servidores hosting son linux. Dicho esto, cambia `$rutaDestino` por :

```
$rutaDestino =  $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/db_server/fotos/".$nombreArchivo;
```

Podriamos optimizar el codigo y dejarlo asi:

```php
#comprobamos la subida del archivo
if ($_FILES['archivo']['error'] != UPLOAD_ERR_OK)   die("Error al subir el archivo.") ;

$nombreArchivo = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
$rutaDestino =  $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/db_server/fotos/'.$nombreArchivo;
#movemos el fichero a la ruta de destino
if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'],$rutaDestino)) die("Error al mover el archivo a la ruta de destino.") ;

#modificamos la fodo del usuario    
$idempleado = $_POST['idempleado'];       
$conexion = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "db");
$sql = "UPDATE usuarios SET userfoto='$nombreArchivo',rutafoto='$rutaDestino' WHERE id_usuarios = '$idusuario'";   
if($conexion->query($sql) != TRUE){
  echo json_encode(['code' => '0' . $conn->error]);
  die();
}

#respondemos correcto
echo json_encode(['code' => '1']);
$conexion->close();
```

Comment: Si lo se esta 'C:/xampp1/htdocs/db_server/fotos/ no es la ruta esa la tengo de manera local , entonces lo declaro asi $rutaDestino =  $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/db_server/fotos/".$nombreArchivo; y al cual le debo de dar permiso al directorio verdad asi lo intentare gracias de antemano.

Comment: esta es la ruta C:/xampp1/htdocs/db_server/fotos/fotoempleados.png pero al colocarla en el frontend por que no se muestra? ya revise la parte de los permisos y si los tienen falta realizar un paso mas para hacer una conversion o algo asi?

Comment: Que tal amigos gracias por tu ayuda @W Aleman, ya vi cual era mi error todo estaba correcto al guardar el archivo , la parte de cargar la imagen se hace apuntando al servidor http://dominio.com.mx/directorio/nombredeimagen.png como ejemplo gracias.